# Media Queries not working on chrome for Iphone

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, google-chrome

I recently noticed that a media query I have on my website doesn't work on the chrome app on my Iphone. It display's fine on laptop, ipad and netbook and works on other mobile browsers just not chrome.

I have checked through this site and tried alot of suggestions but none fix the problem.

Links to the page and the css are below:

http://annbankunited.x10host.com/table.html

http://annbankunited.x10host.com/css/style.css

EDIT: Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda ridiculous but I ran into this problem once when I head a relative path for my style sheet. When I changed it to a full path (so http://annbankunited.x10host.com/css/style.css) it worked.

Try clearing cache as well.

Comment: I will give this a try, its weird cause one media query on the page works and the other works fine in anything but Chrome on the Iphone